# Amazon EC2 Web Server not Serving Content

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing

I was using an EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 Server instance that was working fine but I had to reboot it briefly and since then I have been unable to connect via HTTP/HTTPS or ping it. I can SSH in and Telnet works on both ports 443 and 80 and I have verified that:

1. Apache2 is installed/running
2. MySQL (on local machine/image) is running
3. The Security group has rules to allow all incoming/outcoming
   HTTP/HTTPS traffic for IPV4 and IPV6, and one inbound rule to allow my personal SSH.
4. The DNS records are pointing to the correct IP and have propagated
5. The files to serve are there and valid
6. My /etc/apache2/sites-available and sites-enabled is configured
   correctly/has not changed
7. My Route Table/Internet gateway in AWS is configured correctly
8. My Instances are in the correct VPC
9. The instances are running (obviously)

After all this I still cannot access the site via web/browswer or ping, just SSH and Telnet, isitdownrightnow also reports the website as down. Any ideas whats going on??

EDIT: [Security Group Settings (inbound)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiCzT.png)

EDIT2: [Apache Logs (access.log and error.log)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiL2s.png)

Comment: "Telnet works on both ports" - from where to where - show the output. What do you logs say? What about `ufw status` ?

Comment: Telnet works from my local home machine to the remote AWS instance, will add logs/more screenshots after this edit!

Comment: @varlogtim UFW is inactive.

Comment: Can you curl / ping from the server to itself? Can you curl / ping from a spot instance you set up in the same subnet with appropriate security group / NACL rules? A process of elimination is probably what you'll need to work this out. I suspect it's something on the instance, as a restart doesn't affect AWS infrastructure - it even stays on exactly the same hardware with a reboot - stop / start almost certainly takes it to new hardware.